# Using System.currentTime in distributed service architecture?

Tags: java, distributed-computing

I have two services, service A and service B.

I call a method `doStuff()` on service `B` and it creates an entry in a database with the `system.CurrentTime()` on the computer running `B` code at the time.

I call a method `compareThings()` on service `A` and it queries the service `B` and pulls the entry I just added and takes the timestamp field, call it `tsFromB`. Now, I want to check `system.CurrentTime() - tsFromB`.

My question is, if a difference of `1` minute between computer clock differences matters a lot, is `system.CurrentTime() - tsFromB` from the computer running `Service A` a good choice to make? Would this be correct?

Comment: You cannot trust individual clocks in a distributed architecture, period. The book Designing Data-Intensive Applications has an entire section that describes the problems of that which are plenty. Perhaps worth reading before choosing an alternative here!

Comment: since data is already being stored in database, you have one common clock - use the database time. The computer clocks may be synchronized with network (NTP), but that still can fail. But it all depends a lot on the application...

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, what could go wrong as an example? Will they clocks be that much off? I imagine they shouldn't be off too much since the `system.currentTime()` is the system time, which if connected to a internet connection should have the same time right?

Comment: @jj0td I have added an answer to your question to open a space to discuss that. It is not obvious in your question what is exactly is the purpose of the clock data, but you should definitely read the book I recommended to avoid dangerous architectura problems if the clock data is going to be used for purposes other than just logging.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot trust individual computer clocks for many reasons.

In response to your question in the comment section, I will share an excerpt from Martin Kleppmann's book, Designing Data-Intensive Applications from his section on unreliable clocks.

> - The quartz clock in a computer is not very accurate: it drifts (runs faster or slower than it should). Clock drift varies depending on the
>     temperature of the machine. Google assumes a clock drift of 200 ppm
>     (parts per million) for its servers, which is equivalent to 6 ms drift
>     for a clock that is resynchronized with a server every 30 seconds, or
>     17 seconds drift for a clock that is resynchronized once a day. This
>     drift limits the best possible accuracy you can achieve, even if
>     everything is working correctly.
> - If a computer’s clock differs too much from an NTP server, it may refuse to synchronize, or the local clock will be forcibly reset. Any
>     applications observing the time before and after this reset may see
>     time go backward or suddenly jump forward.
> - If a node is accidentally firewalled off from NTP servers, the misconfiguration may go unnoticed for some time. Anecdotal evidence
>     suggests that this does happen in practice.
> - NTP synchronization can only be as good as the network delay, so there is a limit to its accuracy when you’re on a congested network
>     with variable packet delays. One experiment showed that a minimum
>     error of 35 ms is achievable when synchronizing over the internet,
>     though occasional spikes in network delay lead to errors of around a
>     second. Depending on the configuration, large network delays can cause
>     the NTP client to give up entirely.
> - Some NTP servers are wrong or misconfigured, reporting time that is off by hours. NTP clients are quite robust, because they query several
>     servers and ignore outliers. Nevertheless, it’s somewhat worrying to
>     bet the correctness of your systems on the time that you were told by
>     a stranger on the internet.
> - “Leap seconds result in a minute that is 59 seconds or 61 seconds long, which messes up timing assumptions in systems that are not
>     designed with leap seconds in mind. The fact that leap seconds have
>     crashed many large systems shows how easy it is for incorrect
>     assumptions about clocks to sneak into a system. The best way of
>     handling leap seconds may be to make NTP servers “lie," “by performing
>     the leap second adjustment gradually over the course of a day (this is
>     known as smearing), although actual NTP server behavior varies in
>     practice.
> - “In virtual machines, the hardware clock is virtualized, which raises additional challenges for applications that need accurate
>     timekeeping. When a CPU core is shared between virtual machines, each
>     VM is paused for tens of milliseconds while another VM is running.
>     From an application’s point of view, this pause manifests itself as
>     the clock suddenly jumping forward.
> - “If you run software on devices that you don’t fully control (e.g., mobile or embedded devices), you probably cannot trust the device’s
>     hardware clock at all. Some users deliberately set their hardware
>     clock to an incorrect date and time, for example to circumvent timing
>     limitations in games. As a result, the clock might be set to a time
>     wildly in the past or the future.

Of course, if you decide to get your clock data from another distributed component, then you go again into the classical problems of distributed computing, like what happens if that service that gives you the time is down, or inaccessible, or too slow, etc, etc. And this applies also to the database. Provided that one deals with that, using this global, shared entity would somewhat solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would not use the timestamp from Computer A or B for such cases. I would use the current time from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of NTP(Network Time Protocol) protocol? It is for the time synching of computers on a network to prevent such problems. I advise you to use it instead of solving the side effects of not using such choices. For more information you can follow below links:

[NTP](http://www.ntp.org/)

[NTP wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)

Comment: What if NTP synchronization fails due to network issues, or if the server is so busy that synchronization is delayed, or a gc pause delays the verification, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo sorry but it seems that you look to engineering issues just as like an academic man. There is just a lot of etc. :) which can occur too rarely. As I know it is one of the most popular protocols to solve this issue which it is used even in Google. Additionally, If someone has any real-world experiences in great companies, it is a common solution to use NTP for such a problem. So, your mentioned issues would not be problematic. I suggest you to always read first then compare it with your knowledge. :)

Comment: I think we've had different experiences with this. I have worked on a few applications where servers were under NTP and I spotted drifts in the clocks all the time, which can occur for different reasons. Depending on what is the purpose of the clock info, this can cause important architectural issues. Also, who wants to risk the application functionality or even its architecture on the precision of a third-party app. If a server loses connectivity with NTP for whatever network configuration errors (which happen all the time), nobody would even notice until some weird thing starst to happen.